# 0xC0000005: нарушение прав доступа при записи по адресу 0x00000028

Tags: c, массивы, файлы, struct

Вопрос довольно объёмный, предоставлю всю программу, в которой собственно возникает проблема вместе со всеми комментариями:

**header.h:**

```
  //объявляем символьную константу в которой храним количество символов в поле
//ФИО студента структуры student
#define MAXFNAME 25


//объявляем структуру
typedef struct tagStudent
{
    int studNmb;            //номер студента в списке
    char fname[MAXFNAME];   //ФИО студента
    int roomNmb;            //номер комнаты
    int floor;              //номер этажа

                            //в этих переменных храним ссылку на следующую, предыдущую связанную структуру
    struct tagStudent *pnext, *pprev;
} Student;

//объявляем прототипы функций используемых в программе
void print(Student *p);
void getUser(Student *p);
Student* addEnd(Student *p, Student *end, int stnumb);
void printList(Student *p);
void loadList(Student *p, char *file, Student **pend, Student **pbegin);
void saveList(Student *p, char *file);
int editStd(Student *p, Student **pend, Student **pbegin);
int deleteStd(Student *p, Student **pend, Student **pbegin);
```

**main.c:**

```
 #define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

//подключаем необходимые заголовочные файлы стандартной библиотеки
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
//подключаем заголовочный файл созданный ранее
#include "header.h"

//пишем главную функцию программы
void main()
{
    //объявляем переменные
    //переменная для выбранного пользователем номера команды 
    int n = 0;
    //переменная для временного хранения структуры, для передачи ее из одной функции в другую
    Student std;
    //указатели на первый и последний элемент структуры
    Student *begin = NULL, *end = NULL;
    //пользовательское меню
    //1. добавить запись в список студентов 2. отредактировать запись в списке 
    //3. сохр. список в файл 4. загрузить список из файла 5. вывести список на экран
    //6. выход
L:  printf("\n1.add     3.save      5.print     \n2.edit    4.load      6.exit  \n");
    printf("Input the command number (from 1 to 6): ");
    //сохраняем введёное пользователем значение в переменной n
    scanf("%d", &n);

    //в зависимости от введённого пользователем значения (1-5) запуск. соотв. функции,
    //при вводе "6" (6й команды) выходим без ошибки
    switch (n)
    {
    case 1: //принимаем значения от пользователя во временную структуру std
        getUser(&std);
        //связываем заполненную пользователем структуру std с имеющимися структурами
        end = addEnd(&std, end, 0);
        //при первом заполнении структуры указатели на 1 и последн структуру равны
        if (begin == NULL) begin = end;
        break;
    case 2: //редактируем выбранную пользователем строку    
        editStd(begin, &end, &begin);
        break;
    case 3: //сохраняем список в файл
        saveList(begin, "list.dat"); break;
    case 4: //загружаем список из файла
        loadList(begin, "list.dat", &end, &begin); break;
    case 5: //печатаем список на экран
        printList(begin); break;
    case 6: //завершаем программу без ошибок (выход)
        exit(0); break;
    }
    //при вводе пользователем значения не равного числу от 1 до 6
    //просим ввести команду еще раз
    goto L;
}
//функции для приема значения от пользователя 
//принимает параметром указатель на структуру
void getUser(Student *p)
{
    Student tmp;
    //поочередно запрашиваем и принимаем информацию от пользователя 
    printf("\nInput name :");
    fflush(stdin);
    fgets(tmp.fname, MAXFNAME, stdin);
    //удаляем символ завершения строки, которые добавился функцией fgets
    tmp.fname[strlen(tmp.fname) - 1] = '\0';
    printf("Input floor: ");
    scanf("%d", &tmp.floor);
    fflush(stdin);
    printf("Input room number: ");
    scanf("%d", &tmp.roomNmb);

    //указатели на пред. след. структуру укажем позже
    tmp.pnext = tmp.pprev = NULL;
    //копируем структуру tmp в структуру по указателю p (входной параметр)
    *p = tmp;
}
/*функция (ф) для связывания заполненной пользователем структуры с имеющимся списком
структур. Ф принимает: заполненную структуру, указатель на последнюю структуру
в списке, номер в списке который необходимо заполнить для добавляемого студента
(т.к. данная функция еще используется при загрузке списка для файла). Ф возвращает: указатель на
структуру который записывается в переменную end-указатель на последнюю структуру*/
Student* addEnd(Student *p, Student *end, int stnumb)
{
    //выделяем память для структуры, помещаем указатель на неё в pAdd
    Student *pAdd = (Student*)malloc(sizeof(Student));
    //заполняем память по адресу pAdd переданной, через параметр указатель p, структурой 
    *pAdd = *p;
    if (end == NULL) //если добавляем первый элемент
    {
        //в указатель end помещаем указатель на заполненную структуру
        end = pAdd;
        //если переданный параметр stnumb равен нулю, тогда номер в списке присваиваем 1
        //иначе значение равное переданному параметру stnumb
        if (stnumb == 0) pAdd->studNmb = 1;
        else pAdd->studNmb = stnumb;
    }
    else //если добавляем не первый элемент
    {
        end->pnext = pAdd; //связываем последний элемент с добавляемым
        pAdd->pprev = end; //связываем добавляем элемент с последним
                           //если переданный параметр stnumb равен нулю, тогда номер в списке присваиваем
                           //номер последней строки в списке плюс один 
        if (stnumb == 0) pAdd->studNmb = end->studNmb + 1;
        else pAdd->studNmb = stnumb;
        end = pAdd;
    }
    //возвращаем указатель на последний элемент 
    return end;
}
/*функция для редактирования выбранных пользователем строк
входящие параметры: указатель на первую структуру,
указатель на указатель последней в списке структуры,
указатель на указатель первой в списке структуры*/
int editStd(Student *p, Student **pend, Student **pbegin)
{
    //объявляем переменные
    int n, k;
    Student *s = NULL, std;
    //выводим список на экран и предлагаем выбрать номер строки
    printList(p);
    printf("Input number of student: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    //находим структуру номер в списке кот. равен выбранному
    while (p != NULL) {
        if (p->studNmb == n) { s = p; break; }
        p = p->pnext;
    }
    //предлагаем выбрать номер команды
L:  printf("\nWhat do you want to do with this string? \n1.edit \n2.delete \n3.exit to the main menu \nInput the command: ");
    scanf("%d", &k);
    switch (k) {
    case 1: //при редактировании строки запрашиваем перевести данные 
        getUser(&std); //сохраняем их в структуру std
                       //в выбранную строку вносим изменения
        strncpy(s->fname, std.fname, sizeof(std.fname));
        s->roomNmb = std.roomNmb; s->floor = std.floor;
        goto M; //выход из цикла
    case 2: //удаляем строку функцией deleteStd, передаём в неё
            //указатель на удаляемую структуру, на первый и последний элементы списка
        deleteStd(s, pend, pbegin); goto M; //выход из цикла
    case 3: goto M; //выход в главное меню
    }
    goto L; //если введенное значение не 1,2,3, переспрашиваем
M:  return 0; //выходим без кода ошибки
}

//удаление строки из списка, параметры идентичные функции editStd
int deleteStd(Student *p, Student **pend, Student **pbegin)
{
    Student *pr = NULL, *pn = NULL; //указатели для пред. след. эл. списка 
    if (p->pnext == NULL) //если удаленная строка последняя
    {
        pr = p->pprev; //сохраняем в pr указатель на предыдущий элемент списка
        if (pr != NULL) //если предыдущий элемент есть
        {
            pr->pnext = NULL;   //обнуляем указатель в пред. элементе
            *pend = pr;         //предыдущий элемент объявляем последним
        }
        else //если предыдущего элемента нет 
        {
            *pend = NULL; //последний и первый элементы списка обнуляем
            *pbegin = NULL;
        }
    }
    else if (p->pprev = NULL) //если удаляемая строка первая
    {
        pn = p->pnext; //сохраняем в pn указатель на следующий элемент списка
        *pbegin = pn;   //указатель на первый элемент меняем на pn
        pn->pprev = NULL; //в след элементе обнуляем указатель на пред. элемент 
    }
    else //если удаляемая строка ни первая, ни последняя
    {
        pn = p->pnext;  //сохраняем в pn указатель на след. элемент списка
        pr = p->pprev;  //сохраняем в pr указатель на предыд. элемент списка
                        //связываем указ-ли предыдущ. и след. элемента так как текущий элемент удаляем
        pn->pprev = p->pprev;
        pr->pnext = p->pnext;
    }
    free(p);  //освобождаем память по указателю текущего элемента
    p = NULL; //обнуляем указатель 
    return 0;
}

void saveList(Student *p, char *file)
{
    //объявляем указатель pf типа FILE, открываем или создаем файл
    //функцией fopen (режим символьной записи), и помещаем указатель на файл в pf
    FILE *pf = fopen(file, "w");
    //если файл успешно открыт/создан
    if (pf != NULL)
    {
        while (p != NULL) //проходимся по всем элементам списка
        {
            //и записываем элементы структур в файл 
            fprintf(pf, "%d %s %d %d\n", p->studNmb, p->fname, p->roomNmb, p->floor);
            p = p->pnext;
        }
        fclose(pf); //закрываем файл
    }
}

//функция загрузки списка из файла, параметры:
//указатель на структуру типа Student, название файла, указатель на
//указатель на первый элемент списка, указатель на указатель на последний элемент списка
void loadList(Student *p, char *file, Student **pend, Student **pbegin)
{
    Student tmp, *ptmp;
    //объявляем указатель pf типа FILE, открываем или создаём файл
    //функцией fopen (режим символьного чтения), и помещаем указатель на файл в pf
    FILE *pf = fopen(file, "r");
    //если файл успешно открыт/создан
    if (pf != NULL)
    {
        //очищаем текущий список структур
        while (p != NULL)
        {
            ptmp = p->pnext;
            deleteStd(p, *pend, *pbegin);
            p = ptmp;
        }
        *pend = NULL;
        *pbegin = NULL;
        //пока не достигнут конец файла читаем данные во временную структуру tmp
        while (!feof(pf))
        {
            fscanf(pf, "%d %s %d %d\n", &tmp.studNmb, &tmp.fname, &tmp.roomNmb, &tmp.floor);
            tmp.pnext = tmp.pprev = NULL;
            //запускаем функцию addEnd, передаём в нее указатель на заполенную временную структуру,
            //указатель на указатель последнего элемента списка, и номер записываемого элемента в списке
            //функция добавит полученную из файла структуру в список
            *pend = addEnd(&tmp, *pend, tmp.studNmb);
            //если элемент первый то последний элемент равен первому элементу
            if (*pbegin == NULL) *pbegin = *pend;
        }
        fclose(pf); //закрываем файл
    }
}

//функция вывода списка на экран принимает указатель на структуру
void printList(Student *p)
{
    //выводим шапку таблицы
    printf("\n%s %s %s %s \n", "# ", "Name              ", "Floor  ", "Room  ");
    printf("%s \n", "-----------------------------------");

    //циклом проходимся по элементам списка и выводим их на экран
    //ниже описанной функцией print
    while (p != NULL)
    {
        print(p);
        p = p->pnext;
    }
}

//функция печати строки списка на экран
void print(Student *p)
{
    printf("%-2d %-25s %-6d %-3d \n", p->studNmb, p->fname, p->floor, p->roomNmb);
}
```

При запуске функции getUser когда читает tmp.fname и tmp.floor, дважды выводит друг за другом "Input Name:Input Floor:". При попытке сохранить массив структур, оно похоже пытается его сохранить, но при попытке загрузить его или отредактировать, сразу же выводит ошибку, ссылаясь на "Вызвано исключение по адресу 0x00C41442: 0xC0000005: нарушение прав доступа при записи по адресу 0x00000028" где-то здесь в функции deleteStd:

```
else //если удаляемая строка ни первая, ни последняя
        {
            pn = p->pnext;  //сохраняем в pn указатель на след. элемент списка
            pr = p->pprev;  //сохраняем в pr указатель на предыд. элемент списка
                            //связываем указ-ли предыдущ. и след. элемента так как текущий элемент удаляем
            pn->pprev = p->pprev;
            pr->pnext = p->pnext;
        }
        free(p);  //освобождаем память по указателю текущего элемента
        p = NULL; //обнуляем указатель 
        return 0;
    }
```

Я понимаю, что с моей стороны задавать вопросы подобного объёма бестактно и признак недалёкого ума, но если бы мне объяснили, в чём же всё-таки здесь проблема до 13 января, буду крайне благодарен. Может, к тому же еще какие-то ошибки найдёте. Спасибо.

Comment: Берете отладчик и отлаживаете. Вы хотя бы увидите на какой строке проблема

Comment: Оно мне говорит, что проблема на 178 строке, к которой обращение идёт со строки 219 в loadList. Но в чем сама проблема то? 

178 строка - это pr->pnext = p->pnext; в самом низу вопроса выделил отдельно этот кусок кода.

Comment: [вот](https://i.imgur.com/uBX33pO.png)

Comment: Нам всем тут ну ОЧЕНЬ удобно считать строки в вашем коде, который разбит на несколько частей, да еще и явно с пропусками. Подумайте о том, что вам говорят "падает в 123-й строке" и дают не весь код. Удобно строку находить?

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/6hBs0bp.png

Comment: А теперь подумайте о том, что вам правильной код дали картинкой. Очень удобно с картинки набирать, да?

Comment: Еще раз извините. Лучше так оставлю ту функцию, на которой всё и падает. Строка 31 в pastebin: https://pastebin.com/NHkcTG4e

В вопросе весь код, больше ничего другого нет. Это вся-вся программа.

Comment: А теперь представьте, что вам нужно зайти через TOR на ресурс, который в вашей стране не доступен.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*"У нас глаз так, без мелкоскопа, пристрелямши." Н.Лесков "Левша"*

Не

```
(p->pprev = NULL) //если удаляемая строка первая
```

a

```
(p->pprev == NULL) //если удаляемая строка первая
```

Что происходит, надо объяснять?

Здесь делается не сравнение с `NULL`, a присвоение `p->pprev` значения `NULL`. Оператор присвоения возвращает новое значение левой части. Это `p->pprev` с значением `NULL` проверяется на истинность. Так как `NULL` соответствует `false`, в `else if` мы не заходим, а попадаем в `else`, где обращаемся к `p->pprev->pnext` в в строке `pr->pnext = p->pnext;` - БУМ!

```
else if (p->pprev = NULL) //если удаляемая строка первая
{
    pn = p->pnext; //сохраняем в pn указатель на следующий элемент списка
    *pbegin = pn;   //указатель на первый элемент меняем на pn
    pn->pprev = NULL; //в след элементе обнуляем указатель на пред. элемент 
}
else //если удаляемая строка ни первая, ни последняя
{
    pn = p->pnext;  //сохраняем в pn указатель на след. элемент списка
    pr = p->pprev;  //сохраняем в pr указатель на предыд. элемент списка
                    //связываем указ-ли предыдущ. и след. элемента так как текущий элемент удаляем
    pn->pprev = p->pprev;
    pr->pnext = p->pnext;
}
```

Comment: На всякий случай объясните. Смутно начинаю понимать, конечно, но заранее спасибо.

Comment: Дошло. Теперь я чётко вижу, что еще надо исправить будет. Спасибо большое.